# Mockito and TextUtils

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing

I've encountered some strange behavior using mockito to test my presenter class in my android application.

I have a test which fails even though it passes on my device. The misbehaving code:

```
@Test
public void testValidPhoneNumber() throws Exception {
    String phone = "0123456789";
    assert(TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(phone));
}
```

The above fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.usehomeroom.vasuki.auth.RegisterPresenterTest.testValidPhoneNumber(RegisterPresenterTest.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)


Process finished with exit code 255
```

Comment: something to do with static methods, try separating that assert statement into assignment and then assert, you might find out the real cause

Comment: String phone = "0123456789";
        boolean isDigitsOnly = TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(phone);
        assert(isDigitsOnly); This also causes an Assertion error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TextUtils doesn't work with mockito.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a late answer, I was thinking of sharing the work-around that I could come up with. The following worked in my case. I ran the test class using the `RobolectricTestRunner` which seems to solve my problem.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class PhoneNumberTest {

    @Test
    public void testIsValidPhoneNumber() {
        Assert.assertEquals(true, isValidPhoneNumber("78425544587"));
    }
}
```

The `isValidPhoneNumber` is a simple function that returns true if the phone number contains all digits and false otherwise.

```
public static boolean isValidPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    if (phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber.trim().isEmpty()) return false;
    else if (!TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(phoneNumber))
        return false;
    else true;
}
```